# How to make x values in a plot as dates inside a function?

Tags: r, text, plot

I have three text file that each  simply consists of 4 columns(each column has 477 values). I managed to plot them like:
plot the first column from each text file and do the same with the rest of columns(figure attached). As you can see, the x axis is presented as numbers but I need it to be presented as date so I tried to specify the date I want, but I got an error related to the length.  I am sure that the date range 03/09/2010 to 23/12/2012 ha length  as the same as the values 477. I am grateful to any help.

```
ref= read.table("D:\\AS_asc.txt", sep="",header=TRUE)
sour1 = read.table("D:\\rre.txt", sep="",header=TRUE) 
  sour2= read.table("D:\\re_asc.txt", sep="",header=TRUE)
  starttime <- strptime("20100903", "%Y%m%d")
   endtime <- strptime("20111223 ", "%Y%m%d")
     xrange <- c(starttime, endtime)
   columns <- paste0("X", 1:4)
   par(mfrow=c(2,2))
  lapply(
 columns,
  function(column)
  {

 plot(xrange,
   ref[[column]],

   ylab = "[[column]]",
  xlab = "[[column]]",
   col  = 2 , main = paste( column )
 )

points(sour1[[column]], col = 'green')
 points( sour2[[column]], col = 'blue')

 }
 )
```

I got this error:

```
 Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

sample of my data:

```
        "X0" "X1" "X2" "X3" 
  0.0369809285234571 0.0222775883686665 0.031094652297596 0.0814025488998284
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data? The general approach is probably going to be to plot without your x axis (`xaxt = "n"`), then add it back in after creating a date sequence for your axis.

Comment: your start time is 1 to short should be:
starttime <- strptime("20100903", "%Y%m%d")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line: `xrange <- c(starttime, endtime)`. That creates a vector with only two dates. You are trying to plot those two dates against a vector of 477 data, hence the error. The solution is to create a sequence of 477 dates to match the data. `xrange <-  seq(from=as.Date(starttime), to=as.Date(endtime), by=1)`

I also fixed your `points` request to include the date vector as x.

```
ref= data.frame(matrix(runif(477*4),ncol=4))    #dummy random data
sour1 = data.frame(matrix(runif(477*4),ncol=4)) #dummy random data
sour2= data.frame(matrix(runif(477*4),ncol=4))  #dummy random data
starttime <- strptime("20100903", "%Y%m%d")
endtime <- strptime("20111223 ", "%Y%m%d")
xrange <-  seq(from=as.Date(starttime), to=as.Date(endtime), by=1) #create date vector
columns <- paste0("X", 1:4)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
lapply(
 columns,
  function(column)
  {
   plot(xrange,
   ref[[column]],

   ylab = "Unit of the y data",    #more descriptive label
   xlab = "Date",                   #more descriptive label
   col  = 2 , main = paste(column)
   )
points(xrange, sour1[[column]], col = 'green') #add date range
points(xrange, sour2[[column]], col = 'blue') #add date range
 }
)
```

[image]